# How to keep default scope data even when scope data changes?

Tags: angularjs

Keep default $scope data even when scope data changes.

```
  $scope.data={"a":"hello world"};

    $scope.data.a="changed data";
```

now become

```
$scope.data={"a":"changed data"};
```

how can i get old $scope data.ie, i need -

```
$scope.data={"a":"hello world"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way with [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)
You can write reset function. This way

```
  $scope.data={"a":"hello world"};
  var originalData = angular.copy($scope.data);

  $scope.data.a="changed data";

  $scope.reset = function() {
     angular.copy(originalData, $scope.data); 
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly assigning it to `$scope.data`, do a copy of it like below :

```
$scope.data2= angular.copy($scope.data);

$scope.data2.a = "changed data";
```

`angular.copy` creates a deep copy of the source object which is `$scope.data` here.

Comment: No problem . Glad I could help :). Please accept the answer if it helped, so that we can work on other questions :)